# What topics do I need to learn in order to understand the following sentence?

Tags: vector-spaces

> The vector space $\mathbb{R}^{a,b}$ is presumed to have nondegenerate signature $\{a,b\}$, where $a/b$ are maximal subspaces of vectors with positive/negative signature...

Here are the terms that I do understand already:

- vector space
- maximal subspace

Here are the terms I do not understand, and could not find a convenient wikipedia page for:

- $\mathbb{R}^{a,b}$ (as opposed to just $\mathbb{R}^{a}$ where $a \in \mathbb{N}$, which I do understand)
- signature, nondegenerate signature, positive/negative signature

Comment: Where did you find this sentence?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick [New Tools for Computational Geometry and rejuvenation of Screw Theory](http://geocalc.clas.asu.edu/pdf/New_Tools_for_Comp_Geom.pdf), pg.2 , paragraph 1

Comment: Looks like quadratic forms to me. I would guess that ${\bf R}^{a,b}$ is just ${\bf R}^{a+b}$ but with the first $a$ coordinates being viewed somehow differently than the last $b$ coordinates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the notation for a generalised Minkowski space.

Vectors in the space have the form $(x_1, \dots, x_a, y_1, \dots, y_b)$, i.e. they are just vectors of $\mathbb{R}^{a+b}$, but this notation additionally defines the "squared length" of such a vector to be $(x_1^2 + \dots + x_a^2) - (y_1^2 + \dots + y_b^2)$.

The maximal subspace with positive signature is a fancy way of saying the subspace explored by the $x$ coordinates, and similarly the $y$ coordinate explore the maximal subspace with negative signature.

The standard example of a Minkowski space is $\mathbb{R}^{3, 1}$ which is used to represent spacetime in Physics. It has three space-like dimensions, and one time-like dimension.